# Cannot find Column[0] runtime error

Tags: c#, .net

This is my piece of code.

```
DataSet ds = //assigning to dataSet from stored procedure

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]; // It has data i checked in debugging..
```

when doing this operation in run time

```
Select("PGroup_strCode = O ")
```

It s throwing an error

> *"Cannot find Column[O]"*  -- ( i made a mistake earlier it is 'O' not zero as mentioned earler )

That column is also present. Can't figure it out the reason.

**UPDATE :**

```
Select("[Cinema_strID] = ABIC")
```

In select part i changed this now error is Cannot find Column[ABIC]

Comment: Are you check in debug mode what columns `dt` has?

Comment: yeah.. It has this column.. I changed the columns also which is present in the table view in DataTable. for all columns it gives this same error :(

Comment: Have you double checked column spelling and its return type ?

Comment: Check the type of `PGroup_strCode`. I'm having a feeling its returning a `string`

Comment: How can you compare `PGroup_strCode` with `Alphabet O` ??

Comment: sorry that's a mistake. its equal sign there..

Comment: Try Select("PGroup_strCode = 'O'")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be careful while using Datatable select statement.

please try this

```
DataRow[] DataDR= ds.Tables[0].Select("[Cinema_strID]='ABIC'");
```

OR

```
DataRow[] DataDR= ds.Tables[0].Select(ds.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName.Trim()+"='ABIC'"); // But this is only when you are sure that the column position wont change in the future
```

Comment: Select(string.Format("Cinema_strID = '{0}'", "ABIC").
I just tried it works.Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old question but to help any future visitors:
if it's a string you need to provide value to filter in single quotes/apostrophe i.e. `'ABIC'`

```
dt.Select("Cinema_strID = 'ABIC'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would have worked if the column content is integer.
If it is string you should  do something like below

```
    string searchVal =  "dummy ID"
    DataRow[] DataDR= ds.Tables[0].Select("ColoumnName= " + "'" + searchVal    + "'");
```